# Where and when does lingering auras resonate in when using detect magic(or greater)?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic

I want to know if the effects of magic have lingering magic auras on their targets and in the places they were cast from/into. Where and when does lingering auras resonate in cases of the following types of spells:

- Instantenous area effect spells (ie.fireball; cone of cold)?
- multitargetet spells that use an area (ie.Sleep; hold person, mass)?
- Spells that mask other spells (ie. Mask dweomer; magic aura)?
- some sort of mixture of answers depending on the actual details of the spell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Detect Magic locates where magic is targetted

With [Detect Magic](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Detect%20Magic), you can detect Lingering Auras, which give some insight into what you're actually detecting

> **Lingering Aura:** A magical *aura lingers after its original source dissipates* (in the case of a spell) or is destroyed (in the case of a magic item).

I don't think many spellcasters 'dissipate' after their spells are cast (I've seen a few Disintegrate, though), so it must be talking about the location magic is targeting.

> If the items or **creatures bearing the auras** are in line of sight,

must then mean creatures that have had spells put on them.

- Instantaneous effects would only leave a Lingering Aura at their point of effect
- Multitarget spells would be detectable on the creatures affected and (probably) also Lingering at the area targeted
- Masking spells do not have an aura (or more specifically, they have a masked aura) or else they wouldn't function as written

### Greater Detect Magic also detects spellcasters

GDM adds to Detect Magic, including

> Additionally, when you use a standard action to concentrate on this spell, you can also study a creature within the spell’s area and attempt a Spellcraft check in order to determine the last spell that the creature cast by identifying lingering traces that the spell left in the caster’s aura.

This is one of the primary ways GDM is an actual improvement over its cantrip counterpart enough to consider using a spell slot on it.

Answer (score 2):

**What things have lingering auras and where?**

> Instantaneous area effect spells (ie.fireball; cone of cold)?

These have lingering auras (they are spells).  It would start lingering immediately after the spell is cast, as instantaneous spells only exist 'for an instant'.  It would linger over the entire area of the spell, in the case of area spells, and on the target/target's square for targeted spells.  Whether the aura would linger also over any distance the spell has traveled between the caster and the target (such as the distance between a mage casting *magic missiles* and the target of the missiles) is not defined by Rules-As-Written, and would be up the GM.

How long the aura would linger is given by the tables in the Detect Magic spell description - a fireball's aura would linger for only 1d6 rounds, as a 3rd level spell.  A *cone of cold* however would linger for 1d6 minutes, as a 5th level spell.

> Multitarget spells that use an area (ie.Sleep; hold person, mass)?

The area effect of the spell would carry the aura.  Likewise, any creatures targeted would carry the lingering aura, even if they move outside that original area of effect (as they are part of the 'Target' entry of the spell).

> Spells that mask other spells (ie. Mask dweomer; magic aura)?

This depends on the specific text of the spell in question.  Magic Aura explicitly says that it masks the aura of an object from Detect Magic - if Detect Magic could detect a spell on the item, it would make Magic Aura pretty pointless.  So it explicitly says it stops aura being detected on the item, and it makes the most sense for that to be the outcome.

> some sort of mixture of answers depending on the actual details of the spell?

It depends on the Target entry.  Anything that is in the Target entry of the spell, or the Area entry of the spell, is affected by the spell.  Some other things may be affected by the spell such that it leaves an aura on them - this is up to the GM.  Such decisions is a large part of why the game has the GM, to adjudicate edge-case situations or alter the rules to make the game make more sense.